# How to calculate deviance residuals when performing logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I would like to get the residual deviance of logistic regression in R.
When I used glm.fit function, I got the following warning about complete separation.

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

So, I used logistf function.

```
cont <- logistf.control(maxit=1000,maxstep = 100)
plcont <- logistpl.control(maxit=1000)
res <- logistf(y ~ x,firth = TRUE, control = cont,plcontrol = plcont)
```

I got the result from using summary(res).

```
> summary(res)
logistf(formula = dat[, j] ~ Dat_res[, i], control = cont, plcontrol = plcont, firth = TRUE)

Model fitted by Penalized ML
Coefficients:
                   coef   se(coef)  lower 0.95 upper 0.95    Chisq        p
(Intercept)   0.1375199 0.11492692 -0.08696857  0.3642894 1.439322 0.230249
Dat_res[, i] -0.7204668 0.05044381 -0.82565105 -0.6269034      Inf 0.000000
             method
(Intercept)       2
Dat_res[, i]      2

Method: 1-Wald, 2-Profile penalized log-likelihood, 3-None

Likelihood ratio test=895.6586 on 1 df, p=0, n=1000
Wald test = 203.9916 on 1 df, p = 0
```

From this result, I would like to calculate the residual deviance, but I am not sure how to derive it.
I apologize for my lack of understanding, but I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/